# Enable multi-az for running ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can i enable multi-az for a running ec2 instace? I know how to do that for RDS as there is option on the aws console. But for ec2 instaces where can I find this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contrary to RDS, there is no such option for EC2 instances. They are created in a subnet and if you want multi-az you will need to launch multiple instances in different subnets across the availability zones.

Comment: And load balance them to failover?

Comment: Yes, you could then create an ELB and configure this ELB to distribute the traffic between them. Bear in mind that the ELB will reserve one private IP in each of the subnets.

Comment: That is what I thought so since I could not find any option on the AWS console. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more confusing, a single EC2 instance can be attached to two ENIs, each one on a distinct subnet. The ENI (not the instance) is now associated with a subnet. So one EC2 instance can reside in two subnets, but can only reside in one AZ

[https://dev.to/napicella/aws-networking-cheat-sheet-eip-eni-vpc-etc-139m#:~:text=Security%20Groups%20are%20attached%20to,default%20network%20interface%20(eth0).&text=But%20technically%20the%20security%20group,EFS%20creates%20on%20your%20behalf](https://dev.to/napicella/aws-networking-cheat-sheet-eip-eni-vpc-etc-139m#:%7E:text=Security%20Groups%20are%20attached%20to,default%20network%20interface%20(eth0).&text=But%20technically%20the%20security%20group,EFS%20creates%20on%20your%20behalf).

Comment: You should consider to provide an answer in full. The link you supplied are pointing to non-SO web resource. If it gets broken - your answer will become useless.